# Export string values to .txt file

Tags: vba, string, printing, export, txt

I begin in VBA and for my job, I have to analyse excel sheets and export my resume to .txt file.

I was able to create the name of my saving file ("NomFichier") - Yes, it's french ;) - and Also my path by choosing the emplacement of the saving file ("Emplacement")

During my analyse, i stock my values into a string ("Hor (30)")

I am now searching ways to export the values of the string to .txt file using the path and name of the file...Can somebody help me ?

Here is my code for the name of the file and the finding path processus :

```
   'Nom du tableau deviens nom du fichier .txt
   'Name of the file to be save

    Dim NomFichier As String
    NomFichier = Tableau_X & "_" & Titre
    
    'Emplacement du fichier txt à enregistrer
    'Location of the file to be save

    Dim Emplacement As String
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Show
    Emplacement = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
    Set diaFolder = Nothing
```

"..."

Answer (score 1):

To write to a text file you need the file path (which you have) and the next available file number, which is easy to get. Then you 'open' the file number for modification.

```
Dim fileNum As Integer

fileNum = FreeFile

Open Emplacement For Output As fileNum
Print #fileNum, "write your information here"
Close fileNum
```

You can use as many `Print` statements as you need or use an array together with a loop or a variety of other ways to add your data. The `#fileNum` refers to the file you're modifying with the `Print` statement and the next bit can be a variable or hard coded.

This code creates a new file but you can use `Input` to read from a file and `Append` to add onto an existing file. You can read more on ways to interact with files here: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-guide-text-files